# Install Arduino IDE in Raspian Strech Desktop

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, arduino

I'm using a Raspian Stretch in Virtual Machine (VMWare).
I follow the steps to install Arduino IDE in Linux ARM version.

The software are installed OK, but when i click to open IDE, nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Best Regards,
Felipe Fonseca

Comment: Link the guide you used for the install.
Also, if you can find the path of the install, you can try launching it from the terminal.

Comment: Dont beleive vmware can run an arm ISO,   I think you are running the desktop ISO of Raspian, which is not built for an arm processor.   VMware cant emulate an arm processor.